# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: last_name

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this code working having my desired output

```
String hql = "FROM Employee ORDER BY last_name";  
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);  
employeeList = query.list();
```

I tried this code but it fails

```
String hql = "FROM Employee E ORDER BY E.last_name";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
employeeList = query.list();
```

Here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: last_name of: com.hibernate.exercise6.model.Employee [FROM com.hibernate.exercise6.model.Employee E ORDER BY E.last_name]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:631)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:101)
at com.hibernate.exercise6.service.EmployeeFunctions.listEmployees(EmployeeFunctions.java:208)
at com.hibernate.exercise6.app.GUIMain.displayListMenu(GUIMain.java:329)
at com.hibernate.exercise6.app.GUIMain.manageRecords(GUIMain.java:140)
at com.hibernate.exercise6.app.GUIMain.main(GUIMain.java:62)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: last_name of: com.hibernate.exercise6.model.Employee [FROM com.hibernate.exercise6.model.Employee E ORDER BY E.last_name]
at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:152)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:521)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:623)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: last_name of: com.hibernate.exercise6.model.Employee
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1801)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:505)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:660)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:204)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:104)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1013)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1286)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.orderExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1860)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.orderExprs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1657)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.orderClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1630)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:652)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:311)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:259)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
... 11 more
```

Employee.java

```
package com.hibernate.exercise6.model;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Employee extends Id{
private int uniqueId;
private Name nameInfo;
private Address addressInfo;
private OtherInfo otherInfo;
private Set contact;
private Set role;

public Employee() {}

public Employee(Name nameInfo, Address addressInfo, OtherInfo otherInfo){
    this.nameInfo = nameInfo;
    this.addressInfo = addressInfo;
    this.otherInfo = otherInfo;
}

public void setId(int uniqueId){
    this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
}
public int getId(){
    return uniqueId;
}

public void setName(Name nameInfo){
    this.nameInfo = nameInfo;
}
public Name getName(){
    return nameInfo;
}

public void setAddress(Address addressInfo){
    this.addressInfo = addressInfo;
}
public Address getAddress(){
    return addressInfo;
}

public void setOtherInfo(OtherInfo otherInfo){
    this.otherInfo = otherInfo;
}
public OtherInfo getOtherInfo(){
    return otherInfo;
}

public void setContacts(Set contact){
    this.contact = contact;
}
public Set getContacts(){
    return contact;
}

public void setRole(Set role){
    this.role = role;
}
public Set getRole(){
    return role;
}

public static Comparator<Employee> employeeGwaComparator = new Comparator<Employee>(){
    public int compare(Employee emp1, Employee emp2){
        String emp1Gwa = String.valueOf(emp1.otherInfo.getGwa());
        String emp2Gwa = String.valueOf(emp2.otherInfo.getGwa());

        return emp1Gwa.compareTo(emp2Gwa);
    }       
};
}
```

Name.java

```
package com.hibernate.exercise6.model;

public class Name{
private String firstName,
                                lastName,
                                middleName,
                                suffix,
                                title;

public Name() {}

public Name(String title, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName, String suffix){
    this.title = title;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.suffix = suffix;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
} 

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName){
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
public String getMiddleName(){
    return middleName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName){
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public void setSuffix(String suffix){
    this.suffix = suffix;
}
public String getSuffix(){
    return suffix;
}
}
```

Shouldn't the first code and second code behave the same way? only an alias was introduced, am i correct?

Comment: could you post `Employee` code?

Comment: You don't have `last_name` in your `Employee` class. It should be `lastName` in your HQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In HQL you access the real column name by the entity's property. In your case the property name is `lastName` and the column name is `last_name`. So if you are using HQL you'll have to use properties, you can use column name if you want to implement `NativeQuery`.
2. You are performing a `SELECT` clause on `Employee` entity which has `name` as property and this last have `lastName` as property as well. So your query must be written as bellow :

   ```
   String hql = "FROM Employee E ORDER BY E.name.lastName";  
   Query query = session.createQuery(hql);  
   employeeList = query.list();
   ```

Comment: Good answer! i want to add to the answer - use Criteria API. Its saved query language. Hibernate will construct query without you.

It looks like
return createCriteria(Employee.class)
.addOrder(Order.asc("name")).list()

Comment: it should actually be `E.Name.lastName` since `lastName` is a field in the component `Name` of `Employee`, thanks for the idea