# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve propert

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get a sum of a column in table.

```
public class PaymentLogDAO extends AbstractModel<PaymentLog> {
    public PaymentLogDAO() {
        super(PaymentLog.class);
    }
        public BigDecimal sum(String keyword) {
        try {
            if (!sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive())
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();    
            Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createQuery("select sum(p.Payment) "
                            + "from PaymentLog p "
                            + "where p.TransId =:TransId");
            query.setParameter("TransID", keyword);
            return (BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return BigDecimal.valueOf(0);    
        }

    }
}
```

And it got error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: TransId of: entities.PaymentLog [Select p from entities.PaymentLog p where p.TransId like :TransId]

This is my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PaymentLog"
    ,schema="dbo"
    ,catalog="Project2"
)
public class PaymentLog  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int id;
     private LoanLog loanLog;
     private Date transDate;
     private BigDecimal payment;


    public PaymentLog() {
    }


    public PaymentLog(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public PaymentLog(int id, LoanLog loanLog, Date transDate, BigDecimal payment) {
       this.id = id;
       this.loanLog = loanLog;
       this.transDate = transDate;
       this.payment = payment;
    }

    public PaymentLog(int id, LoanLog loanLog) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

     @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="TransId")
    public LoanLog getLoanLog() {
        return this.loanLog;
    }

    public void setLoanLog(LoanLog loanLog) {
        this.loanLog = loanLog;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="TransDate", length=23)
    public Date getTransDate() {
        return this.transDate;
    }

    public void setTransDate(Date transDate) {
        this.transDate = transDate;
    }


    @Column(name="Payment", scale=4)
    public BigDecimal getPayment() {
        return this.payment;
    }

    public void setPayment(BigDecimal payment) {
        this.payment = payment;
    }

}
```

This is my LoanLog entities `TransId` in `PaymentLog` is foreign key of `Id` in `LoanLog`

```
/**
 * LoanLog generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="LoanLog"
    ,schema="dbo"
    ,catalog="Project2"
)
public class LoanLog  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int id;
     private Account account;
     private CustInfo custInfo;
     private LoanInfo loanInfo;
     private Date loanDate;
     private BigDecimal amount;
     private Integer duration;
     private Integer payingPeriod;
     private BigDecimal rate;
     private Set<PaymentLog> paymentLogs = new HashSet<PaymentLog>(0);
     private Set<FineLog> fineLogs = new HashSet<FineLog>(0);

    public LoanLog() {
    }


    public LoanLog(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public LoanLog(int id, Account account, CustInfo custInfo, LoanInfo loanInfo, Date loanDate, BigDecimal amount, Integer duration, Integer payingPeriod, BigDecimal rate, Set<PaymentLog> paymentLogs, Set<FineLog> fineLogs) {
       this.id = id;
       this.account = account;
       this.custInfo = custInfo;
       this.loanInfo = loanInfo;
       this.loanDate = loanDate;
       this.amount = amount;
       this.duration = duration;
       this.payingPeriod = payingPeriod;
       this.rate = rate;
       this.paymentLogs = paymentLogs;
       this.fineLogs = fineLogs;
    }

      @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="EmployId")
    public Account getAccount() {
        return this.account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="CustId")
    public CustInfo getCustInfo() {
        return this.custInfo;
    }

    public void setCustInfo(CustInfo custInfo) {
        this.custInfo = custInfo;
    }

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LoanId")
    public LoanInfo getLoanInfo() {
        return this.loanInfo;
    }

    public void setLoanInfo(LoanInfo loanInfo) {
        this.loanInfo = loanInfo;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="LoanDate", length=23)
    public Date getLoanDate() {
        return this.loanDate;
    }

    public void setLoanDate(Date loanDate) {
        this.loanDate = loanDate;
    }


    @Column(name="Amount", scale=4)
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }


    @Column(name="Duration")
    public Integer getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }


    @Column(name="PayingPeriod")
    public Integer getPayingPeriod() {
        return this.payingPeriod;
    }

    public void setPayingPeriod(Integer payingPeriod) {
        this.payingPeriod = payingPeriod;
    }


    @Column(name="Rate", precision=10, scale=4)
    public BigDecimal getRate() {
        return this.rate;
    }

    public void setRate(BigDecimal rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="loanLog")
    public Set<PaymentLog> getPaymentLogs() {
        return this.paymentLogs;
    }

    public void setPaymentLogs(Set<PaymentLog> paymentLogs) {
        this.paymentLogs = paymentLogs;
    }

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="loanLog")
    public Set<FineLog> getFineLogs() {
        return this.fineLogs;
    }

    public void setFineLogs(Set<FineLog> fineLogs) {
        this.fineLogs = fineLogs;
    }




}
```

How can I solve it? 
Thank you very much

Comment: `p.loanLog `  instead of  `p.TransId `

Comment: this question might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494219/caused-by-org-hibernate-queryexception-could-not-resolve-property-last-name/38498696#38498696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didnt post your `LoanLog` entity but i guess you have an `id` property of `LoanLog` or sth similar, so try this

```
select sum(p.Payment) "
+ "from PaymentLog p "
+ "where p.loanLoag.id =:TransId
```

you are referencing a `transId` property inside your `PaymentLog` entity which doenst exist in java. It exists in database, but since you are not executing a native query, query has to conform to the java rules, which means: find the property inside the entity and `transId` property doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this URL (refer to Select clause) , the fields have to be part of the Entity that you have. So i guess your select must refer to Id field and not TransId (also i think Id has to be mapped to TransId since the names are different)
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm